# http connection using http-outbound gateway for parallel requests

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to optimize http-outbound can I use spring integration inbound connection factory But i see its single threaded can i improve it to make parallel  requests.?

```
class CustomClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory{

}
```

```
</beans:bean>

 <beans:bean id="verifier"
      class="myNullHostnameVerifier">

</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="headerMapper" class="org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper"
            factory-method="outboundMapper">
    <beans:property name="outboundHeaderNames" value="${mapHeaders}"/>
    <beans:property name="userDefinedHeaderPrefix" value=""/>
</beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question isn't fully clear. You really can inject any `ClientHttpRequestFactory` implementation to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`.

For example `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` is based on the Apache Commons HttpClient which has PoolManager feature.

Or `Netty4ClientHttpRequestFactory`, which is based on the `int ioWorkerCount = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors() * 2;` for multi-threading.

Comment: My simplehttplclientconnectionfactory did not scale i feel its making single threaded.Hence I fee i can invoke parallel.should i do executor or some parallel connection pooling

Comment: Well, if your upstream is single thread anyway any pooling won't help here

Comment: I am using spring xd where stream looks like  s3poller | processor| http-client|rabbit sink

Comment: where http-client is my custom http client

Comment: OK. So, maybe your XD is `single-node` and that might not be a surprise that we are single-threaded there from the S3 source to http-client sink...

Comment: http-connection manager/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory pooling with concurrent parameter and   gave a better ps.Thanks